# How to share TinyMCE Javascript source across multiple ASP.Net sites

Tags: javascript, tinymce, code-sharing

I'm using the Moxie code TinyMCE text editor (http://www.tinymce.com/) for content entry on a number of sites. At the moment I have the tiny_mce folder sitting in the folder of each site. This means that I have lots of copies of the same .js files.

I think it would be better to have one copy of the tiny_mce folder and reference it for each site - so if I make a change, or upgrade the tiny_mce I only have to do it once. Also, if I make a new site I can reference the same one to save needing to upload or copy another 9Mb of duplicated files onto the server.

I have tried putting the tiny_mce into a folder outside the individual websites and setting it up as a site on localhost that they can see.

I then include the javascript from each site like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/MCE/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

I'm pretty sure the the file can be found by the site - I've tested with a simple javascript alert box test which works fine - and if I "View Source" and check the link it's using, I can access the tiny_mce.js file - which is the correct file.

However, the tiny_mce doesn't work.

I'm guessing there are some kind of dependencies or configurations that I'm not aware of that are causing a problem, but I'm not sure quite where to start to find out what isn't working. (I don't get any errors, it just doesn't load the tiny_mce)

Has anyone managed to get tiny_mce to share it's source files across multiple sites? Does tiny_mce require the .js files to be inside the root folder of the site in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone managed to get tiny_mce to share it's source files across
>   multiple sites?

I have not tried it yet.

> Does tiny_mce require the .js files to be inside the root folder of
>   the site in order to work?

No.

Depending on your server system and in case your different website files are stored on one physical server device you could use a hardlink or softlink to the shared tiny_mce_folder (which should be accessible from the net too).

Comment: Linking to the tiny_mce folder doesn't seem to be a problem, I can resolve the URLs. I can link to other .js files and they run as expected. However, the tiny_mce does not initialize when I link to an instance that's not in the root directory of the site - any clues to what might be the issue?